# returning a variable in a span elements it is returning the variable as a string

Tags: javascript

I have the following code is there anyway to use a variable in it?  It is returning the variable as a string and not returning the value of the variable.

```
 replace = replace.replace(new RegExp(amerMatch[i] + "\\.", "i"), `<span class="highlight">library[amerMatch[i]]</span>` + ".")
```

result:

Can you toss this in the library[amerMatch[i]] for me?

Comment: I'm making an automatic question editing tool. Do you mind if I add this question to a dataset?

Comment: Yeah feel free to use my question.  Yeah that article helped I didn't know that it was called a template literal so it was hard to search for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `${ }`

```
`<span class="highlight">library[${amerMatch[i]}]</span>`
```

Comment: Yeah thanks that worked I havent used template literals much.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use `eval(replace)` to get the result of library[amerMatch[i]]

```js
replace = replace.replace(new RegExp(amerMatch[i] + "\\.", "i"), `<span class="highlight">library[amerMatch[i]]</span>` + ".")
var s = eval(replace)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).